# What does this quote about char pointers mean?

Tags: c++

I've read a paragraph but I can't understand what does it mean....can anyone please explain? the paragraph is :

> processing a single character as a
>   char*string can lead to a fatal
>   runtime error. a char* string is a
>   pointer probably a large integer.
>   however a character is a small
>   integer(ascii 0-255). on many systems,
>   dereferencing a char vaalue causes an
>   error, because low memory addresses
>   are reserved for special purposes such
>   as operating system interrupt
>   handlers- so "memory violations"
>   occur.

Comment: I should say that this passage sooo misses the point :)

Comment: This question is most probably C, rather than C++. Few times you will see in C++ texts `char * string` (in C++ `string` is a type, and even if being in the `std` namespace it won't collide with that declaration, most people avoid calling their strings `string`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you shouldn't do something like:

```
char *pCh = 'A';  // this is the value 0x41 (assuming ASCII).
char Ch = *pCh;   // probably not what you wanted.
```

because there is a vast difference between a character and a character *pointer.*

In fact, a decent compiler should give you a warning when you attempt to do something like that.

The rest of it explains one *possible* effect. If you're working in a system where `char` values are eight bits, they will only be able to hold values from 0 through 255 inclusive (the ISO C standard allows char values to be larger but it's fairly uncommon). It's very unlikely that a pointer chosen at random from that value set will be useful.

It's not *totally* out of the question since you may be on an embedded system where you have memory-mapped I/O down there but, in that case, you'd be more likely to use something like `#define IOPORT7 0x0041` and use `IOPORT7` rather than `'A'`.

Pointers, on the other hand, tend to be able to point at your entire address space, which can be 32 bits wide (or larger). 32 bits gives you about four *billion* possible values where a pointer can point to.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just wrong. If pCh is a pointer to character, you can of course dereference it to retrieve the character pointed to. If not, what good would character pointers be after all?

Comment: @Axel, I didn't say you couldn't dereference it. I said you shouldn't do it. And the reason I said that is because you've set it to `'A'`, _not_ `"A"`, which, in ASCII is 0x41 and _very_ unlikely to be a valid pointer. Just because you _can_ do something doesn't make it a good idea :-)

Comment: It is a valid pointer. It's just not a pointer to a zero terminated string.

Comment: Perhaps you should change `char Ch = *pCh;` to something like `strcpy(pCh2, pCh)` since the above assignment to Ch is perfectly valid.

Comment: so paxdiablo....is it like char *pch='a'; means pch holds value 97 and is a pointer to another char whereas char *pch="avinash"; means that pch holds the pointer pointing to a of avinash.

Comment: I meant valid in the context of "points to something useful" rather than something you can dereference. But I still don't see why you downvoted the _answer_ since that wasn't _in_ the answer. But, I'll clarify anyway.

Comment: @Axel: sorry, that's _assuming_ you downvoted, I can't be sure of that and I didn't want to accuse you falsely.

Comment: This could well be what it means. On C++ you would get a compiler error on the first line. Not sure if you wouldn't get one in C too, which has some type-safety but it is not as strong as C.

Comment: @CashCow, g++ gives no error, even with `-Wall` and `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd dump the book or whereever you got that quote from. What is probably meant is you shouldn't try something like this:

```
char c = 'a';
strcmp(&c,"a"); // might accidentally work on some systems, but behaviour is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

It means, if you have a single character, i.e.:

```
char c = 'p';
```

Do not try to dereference c, i.e., to do `*c`, because it will lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little worried about the source of that paragraph -- it feels pretty ancient.

Every modern operating system provides [protected memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection). Every process gets its own address space, and the physical machine's low memory is *not* accessible to programs without performing some pretty significant operations (such as `iopl(2)` or `ioperm(2)` on Linux systems).

The low memory is not mapped into processes because it is the easiest way to catch attempts to write to the `NULL` pointer (which is essentially the address `0x0`) and `char` variables (rather than `char *` variables). The OS could perfectly well map the page at virtual address `0x0` to any page of memory it wants. (Mapping the zero-page is sometimes required for compatibility mode execution of ancient or arcane systems.)

Of course, if you're reading a guide on programming machines without [MMUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), then it makes some sense, but I'd still be wary.