# character pointers

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [character pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231334/character-pointers)

Is it not that `'a'` is decoded to its ascii code value and the following statement becomes equivalent to `char *pch= 197`. Now `pch` will point to the char in address location 197

```
char *pch='a';   //if not then what does this statement mean
```

Comment: What is 197? Memory address? Does this address belong to the program?

Comment: I am doubting whether to close it as exact duplicate or not a real question. If there is something in the 'duplicate' that you do not understand, provide a sensible question. This, as it is, is a statement.

Answer (score 2):

This statement will not compile `char *pch='a';`. You are trying to assign the ascii char 'a' to pointer to char !

Did you mean `char *pch="a";`

Why do you want to access location 197. 
On most PC Any access to the 0 page raise a memory violation.

Comment: +1 `char *pch="a";` would make sense

Comment: @sarnold: It does compile in C, but the question is tagged C++, and in C++ this is an error.

Comment: @sarnold: no it *doesn't*: http://ideone.com/etzze

Comment: Ah, C++ _did_ improve some aspects from C. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas: it compiles in C, but not strict C99: http://ideone.com/xGW0K

Comment: @rubenvb: It looks like you are giving the -Werror option to GCC, which makes warnings into errors, so in reality it is still just a warning? Or do I miss something?

Comment: I guess that's what strict C99 means... all in all, it's still invalid in C++ (and on a personal note, should be invalid in C `;)`).

Answer (score 2):

This line should not compile at all, at least in C++.

In this line, you create a pointer to character (char *) with name 'pch'. Then, you try to initialize it to character 'a' - that is not possible, because pointers can be initialized only with address of some object, or with null pointer (0).

<strike>I think that in C it is illegal too, but I'm not sure about it.</strike>

If you want to set up the pch variable to point to the location under the address 197, you can try one of the following:

```
char *pch = (char *) 197;
char *pch = reinterpret_cast<char*>( 197 ); // C++ only
```

Comment: It does initialize a pointer, but it will not get you very far, as memory at address 197 is unlikely to be a part of your program. Don't try this at home kids!

Answer (score 1):

basically ,

you are storing a char in a pointer which is not valid in C.

a pointer should hold an address of its type.
 but not a value of its type.